# on_message() event only react every x minutes by storing time

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I am trying to have the bot tell users to go to bed if they send a message in a specific time period, but only have the bot react every x minutes. This is done by checking if the difference in time between current and last message is above x. Currently the output is simply nothing - not even errors.

I've managed to get an equivalent of the desired result in "normal" python with:

```py
import datetime
import json
now = datetime.datetime.now()
nowHourMin = float( now.hour ) + ( float( now.minute )/60 )   

def get_time():
    filename = "messageRecord.json"
    try:                                 #If file exists, get time of last message
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            lastMessage = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:            #If file doesn't exists, create it and store current time
        lastMessage = nowHourMin
        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            json.dump(lastMessage, f)
    return lastMessage

def update_time():                       #Store current time
    filename = "messageRecord.json"
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        json.dump(nowHourMin, f)           
    
def message_responder():
    lastMessage = get_time()
    dt = nowHourMin - lastMessage
    if (nowHourMin < 23 ) and (dt >0.01):
        print("Please go to bed, it is getting late")
    update_time()

message_responder()
```

But when I try to adapt the code to the discord library, I fail to get any result. The json file is not created, and when I create one myself nothing is written to the file. It don't get any errors either, simply nothing. Other commands and events work fine.
Here is the discord.py version:

```py
import discord
import json
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

now = datetime.datetime.now()
nowHourMin = float( now.hour ) + ( float( now.minute )/60 )

async def get_time():
    filename = "messageRecord.json"
    try:                                #If file exists, get time of last message
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            lastMessage = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:           #If file doesn't exists, create it and store current time
        lastMessage = nowHourMin
        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            json.dump(lastMessage, f)
    return lastMessage

async def update_time():
    filename = "messageRecord.json"
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        json.dump(nowHourMin, f)                       

def message_responder(message):
    lastMessage = get_time()                            #Get time of last message from "messageRecord.json"
    dt = nowHourMin - lastMessage                       #Time difference
    if (message.author != client.user) and (nowHourMin < 23 ) and (dt >0.01):   #Values will be adjusted once bot works
        await message.channel.send("Please go to bed, it is getting late")
    else:
        await message.channel.send("Dummy text")        #Will be removed once code works, just to confirm bot is working.
    await update_time()                                 #Updates lastMessage to now

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await message_responder(message)
    await client.process_commands(message)              #Prevents on_message()from overwriting commands
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to await `get_time()` since it's an asynchronous function. You also need to make `message_responder()` asynchronous:

```py
async def message_responder(message): #<- here
    lastMessage = await get_time() #<- and here
    dt = nowHourMin - lastMessage
    if (message.author != client.user) and (nowHourMin < 23 ) and (dt >0.01):
        await message.channel.send("Please go to bed, it is getting late")
    else:
        await message.channel.send("Dummy text")
    await update_time()
```